# Make vue widget background transparent

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify to build a widget, which is embedded into another website like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="component-styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="height: 3000px; background-color: pink; opacity: 0.5;"></div>
    <vue-widget style="position: fixed; bottom:0; right: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1000;"></vue-widget>
    <script src="component.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is what index.html looks like:

[image]

How can I modify my Vue widget to allow the pink div to show through it's background, while keeping the button opaque?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding `style=" background: transparent;"` to my  element in App.vue.

Comment: This is the default value so it's not clear from your question why that was necessary

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the css opacity

```
<vue-widget style="position: fixed; bottom:0; right: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1000;opacity: 0.5">
```

Comment: This sets the opacity for the entire widget. I only want the background of the Vue widget to be transparent, not the button itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding "background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1)" where the last number is the opacity of the background, so you can adjust it to your will.

```
<vue-widget style="position: fixed; bottom:0; right: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1000;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);">
```